# How to make HTTP GET and POST calls from a webpage?

Tags: html, http, post, get

What is the easiest way to make HTTP GET AND POST calls to a HTTP Server from a webpage?

I want to create a simple webpage, where a user inputs data, which is then passed on to a HTTP Server.  The response from the HTTP Server has to be displayed back on the webpage.

Please give me some example since I am new to web page development.

Comment: One of the easiest ways I know of is to import jQuery and use $.get and $.post.

Answer (score 0):

I use a php framework called Laravel. Checkout [Laracasts](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch-2018) to learn more about how to make HTTP requests with it. Jeffrey Way makes these videos and explains complex concepts in a clear, accessible way, which is great for people just starting out in web development. I've been using this framework for about 1.5 years now, and I've learned a lot from these videos. I still am learning, though. I hope this helps you!